# Load content inside div from another page with a url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I currently have Jquery tabs for different content on a page but this does not help me SEO wise as google and other places will not pick up this content.

I am looking for "tabs" but instead when you click on a link it loads that bit of information.

An example of this would be here http://www.gamespot.com/watch-dogs

You click on a "tab" say reviews and it loads that content along with a url of http://www.gamespot.com/watch-dogs/reviews/

I am looking to replicate something like this rather than using Jquery tabs.

Your help would be grand!

Comment: try using $("#yourDiv").load('url')

Comment: That site is only using the tabs visually. In reality they are links to different pages.

Comment: Anything you load with Javascript won't be picked up by search engines.

Comment: Yeah I am looking for something that will be picked up through search engines that has its own url.

Doesn't need to be tabs as such I know they don't use jquery tabs but I am looking at doing the same as them. Click and link and load information from another page into the main page which has a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myContent"></div>
```

load method:

```
$("#myContent").load("url to your content which you want to load", function(){
    // things which you want to do with.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to be picked up by search engines, it has to be in the original HTML. They won't run scripts that update the DOM on the client. So you need to do it in PHP:

```
<div>
<?php readfile("url"); ?>
</div>
```

However, if the URL is for a full web page, this is probably a bad idea. It will have its own `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags, and these should appear only once on a page, not embedded inside another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's `load` function:

```
$( "#element to put data in" ).load( "address", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
  //what to do when done loading page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make both search engines (which likely won't execute JQuery) and users (who might like dynamic elements) happy, you could do two solutions. You might have a link which when clicked goes to a brand new HTML page. Search engines will follow this link and see a whole separate page. Then, you might have a javascript within your page (or within the link's click event) that intercepts and overrides the original link's target and instead executes something like JQuery's $().load(). To reuse content you could have the target page be capable of loading both with and without a wrapper.

Target File:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['skipWrapper'])) { include('header.php'); } ?>
Here's the content that matters!
<?php if(!isset($_GET['skipWrapper'])) { include('footer.php'); } ?>
```

Source File:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['skipWrapper'])) { include('header.php'); } ?>
Here's the orginal content!
<a href="TargeFile.php" onclick="asyncLoad('TargeFile.php'); return false;">
<?php if(!isset($_GET['skipWrapper'])) { include('footer.php'); } ?>
```

Definition of asyncLoad:

```
function asyncLoad(url) { $('#targetElementId').load(url + '?skipWrapper=true'); }
```

However, it might be best to just stick with the traditional links rather than doing async tabs. Users get confused when the back button doesn't work or when common behaviors (like middle click to open a link in a new browser tab) no longer work.

Comment: I have tried jquery load and it does not seem to be working.

I am looking for something similar to how these guys do it with their tabs.

http://codecanyon.net/item/modern-html5-responsive-video-player/8406321?WT.ac=category_item&WT.z_author=RikdeVos

As you can see there is a url appended on the end for each tab so you can jump straight to them.

Comment: It may be some sort of compatibility mode of theirs for my setup, but looking at what is returned over the network on my browser when I click those tabs, it is just an ordinary link loading an ordinary page. It's fast (maybe caching?) but it's still loading a complete page HTML, HEAD and all for me.